# Way to detect the domain through PHP

Tags: php, security, session, content-management-system

I'm using SimpleCMS to allow the client to make simple textual changes to their website; however, I'm having some issues here as part of the website is password protected through setting a PHP `$_SESSION` variable. From this secure page, an `if(!isset)` is run on this `$_SESSION` variable to allow or disallow viewing.

Simple CMS works by logging in to www.contenteditor.net and it loads the pages into some sort of frame (I use the word frame loosely). What I want to know is, in addition to my `if(!isset)` test, is there a way to see if the current domain is contenteditor.net and allow them access?

Any Help is appreciated,

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and parse?

Comment: Accessing this variable from the Simple CMS frame still yields my hosting domain as opposed to contenteditor.net

Comment: Your answer led me onto $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'], which I've coded in to recognise the remote host of the content manager (the host is fixed on their side). Login only needs to occur if the correct session variable is filled OR the remote host is not the same one as the editor...

Comment: Ahh, well. Sorry it wasn't dead on, but I'm glad you got it!

Answer (score 2):

Use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to check your host address and $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] could also be used.

Comment: Checking `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is not reliable. Its contents are taken from the `Host:` HTTP request header which can be forged.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in a frame, then no, there's no secure way to do this based on the domain name.

What you could do is, in your authorization code, also allow some kind of URL authorization in addition to the sessions.

When your code editing site opens the page to edit it, append that identifying information to the URL (?auth_token=abcde). You might use a database to generate these tokens from the editor application and read them from the website application, for example. Then the page can be displayed without going through a login form on the website.